# Contar repeticiones de cada letra en una cadena en C

Tags: c, punteros

Necesito que me orienten sobre cómo elaborar un programa que solicite una frase o cadena de texto e imprima las veces que se repitieron las letras por ejemplo que el usuario introduzca la frase `Hola amigos`:

> H: 1
>
> O. 2
>
> l. 1
>
> a- 2
>
> m. 1
>
> i. 1
>
> g. 1
>
> s. 1

Comment: ¿Sensible o insensible a mayúsculas?

Comment: Hola! Deberías mostrar parte de tu código o lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora e indicarle a la comunidad donde tienes problemas o que te está costando resolver, de esa forma es más probable que consigas ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

> cómo elaborar un programa que solicite una frase o cadena de texto

Usa [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):

```
char frase_o_cadena[256] = {0}; // 256 es un tamanyo arbitrario, puede ser insuficiente
scanf("%s", frase_o_cadena);
```

> las veces que se repitieron las letras

Esto es más complicado, en primer lugar no has indicado si debe ser sensible o insensible a mayúsculas, además tampoco indicas si debe tener en cuenta otros caracteres.

#### Primera aproximación

La mejor manera sería, en primer lugar crear un buffer de recuento en que vas acumulando las apariciones de cada letra:

```
unsigned repeticiones['z' - 'a'] = {0}; // Esto deberian tener un tamanyo de 25 elementos
```

Después, recorres tu cadena letra a letra y sumas uno en cada posición de `repeticiones`:

```
for (unsigned indice = 0, fin = strlen(frase_o_cadena); indice < fin; ++indice)
    ++repeticiones[frase_o_cadena[indice] - 'a'];
```

El truco del código anterior consiste en que obtenemos el índice en el que escribir restando `'a'` ([cuyo valor es 97](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Caracteres_imprimibles_ASCII)) a la letra correspondiente en `frase_o_cadena`, así que un texto como `hola` se comportaría así:

- `h` tiene valor 104, al restar 97 queda: 7 (8ª letra del abecedario).
- `o` tiene valor 111, al restar 97 queda: 14 (15ª letra del abecedario).
- `l` tiene valor 108, al restar 97 queda: 11 (12ª letra del abecedario).
- `a` tiene valor 97, al restar 97 queda: 0 (1ª letra del abecedario).

Ten en cuenta que este codigo no cuenta espacios en blanco ni caracteres no alfabéticos, así que cuando se escriba un espacio ( ) cuyo valor es 32, al restar 97 queda en -65 ¡y escribimos fuera de `recuento`!.

#### Sensible a mayúsculas

Para hacerlo sensible a mayúsculas, el arreglo de `repeticiones` debe de ser el doble de grande:

```
unsigned repeticiones[('z' - 'a') * 2] = {0}; // Esto deberian tener un tamanyo de 50 elementos
```

Ahora debemos buscar una manera de separar mayúsculas de minúsculas, sabiendo que el valor de `Z` (90) es menor que el de `a` (97) esto es fácil; una vez sabido podemos escribir en la posición correspondiente de `repeticiones`:

```
for (unsigned indice = 0, fin = strlen(frase_o_cadena); indice < fin; ++indice)
    if (frase_o_cadena[indice] > 'Z') // es minuscula?
        ++repeticiones[frase_o_cadena[indice] - 'a'];
    else // es mayuscula!
        ++repeticiones[(frase_o_cadena[indice] - 'a') + ('z' - 'a')];
```

Con esto conseguimos que las posiciones 0 a 24 del arreglo `repeticiones` contenga el recuento de minúsculas, mientras que las posiciones 25 a 49 contenga el recuento de mayúsculas.

#### Me da igual, ¡cuéntalo todo!

Si queremos tener en cuenta todos los caracteres, es mucho más fácil:

```
// Solo es valido para char de tamanyo 1
unsigned repeticiones[256] = {0};

for (unsigned indice = 0, fin = strlen(frase_o_cadena); indice < fin; ++indice)
    ++repeticiones[frase_o_cadena[indice]];
```

El valor de cada letra, coincide con su posicion en el arreglo de `repeticiones`.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta

- El truco de restar `a` a `z` no funciona para todas las codificaciones de caracteres, si trabajases con [EBCDIC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) (improbable, y mejor que sea así) te fallaría.
- Nada de lo escrito funciona para [caracteres de ancho variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding).
- El código de ejemplo asume que los caracteres carecen de [tildes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde).